# Roots of $z^n=(z+1)^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

**Question:**

Roots of $z^n=(z+1)^n$

1. lie on vertices of regular n-gon
2. lie on circle
3. lie on straight line

**Work:**

I applied binomial theorem to get $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}z^k=0$ which is not of any use..

Also I tried $z=e^{i\theta}$ and $1+z=e^{i\phi}$, so that we have:

$$\cos(n\theta)=\cos(n\phi)\text{ , and}\\\sin(n\theta)=\sin(n\phi)$$

but now we must have $\theta = \phi$, so meaning they lie on straight line as arguments are equal?

Comment: hint: $z^n=(z+1)^n$ iff $(\frac{z}{z+1})^n=1$. Then, you only have to solve the equation $w^n=1$ (plus some special cases).

Comment: Why would $z$ have module $1$ ? First note that $z$ and $1+z$ are non zero, and then you can solve $(\frac{z}{1+z})^n = 1$

Comment: Hmm thanks for hint! I understand the mistake! Still how would we go about solving? z/z+1 is root of unity? Sorry I am a beginner in complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon$ be an $n$-th root of unity; you want to solve
$$
\frac{z}{1+z}=\varepsilon
$$
that is
$$
z=\frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}
$$
which shows you must have $\varepsilon\ne1$, so your equation has $n-1$ solutions.

Now, write $\varepsilon=e^{2\alpha i}$ (we'll determine the possible values of $\alpha$ later on). Then
$$
z=\frac{e^{2\alpha i}}{1-e^{2\alpha i}}=
-\frac{e^{\alpha i}}{e^{\alpha i}-e^{-\alpha i}}=\frac{i}{2\sin\alpha}e^{\alpha i}=\frac{i}{2}(\cot\alpha+i\cos\alpha)
$$
Since we want $\varepsilon^n=1$, we have
$$
\varepsilon=\exp\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)
$$
for $k=1,2,\dots,n-1$ and so we have $\alpha=k\pi/n$: the solutions are
$$
z=\frac{i}{2}\left(\cot\frac{k\pi}{n}+i\cos\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)
\qquad k=1,2,\dots,n-1
$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe $0$ can't be a solution. So the equation is equivalent to 
$$\biggl(1+\frac 1z\biggr)^n=1\iff1+\frac1z=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2ik\pi}n}\quad(0\le k<n)$$
We deduce that, for $k\ne 0$, 
$$z=\dfrac1{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2ik\pi}n}-1}=\frac{\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{ik\pi}n}}{\mathrm e^{\tfrac{ik\pi}n}-\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{ik\pi}n}}=\frac{2i\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{ik\pi}n}}{\sin\tfrac{k\pi}n}=\frac2{\sin\tfrac{k\pi}n}\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac\pi2-\tfrac{ik\pi}n}\quad (0<k<n).$$